# Do query value based on integer length

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, select

I have `table1` like this

[image]

and the expected result like this

[image]

How I can do that? I don't know what I must search.

Comment: The first thing to do is to google “postgresql String functions” that will usually find you a page to start looking for a suitable function

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has a neat [`repeat` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html):

```
SELECT col1, col2, REPEAT(col1, col2)
FROM   table1
```

Answer (score 0):

use REPEAT
https://w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/repeat-function.php

```
    select col1,col2,REPEAT(col1,col2) from table1
```